# Voice Control Offline

Tags: google-now

Is there a way to do "Ok Google" offline?
Basically I do not have a data contract.

Comment: "Alternatively" you should see: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) But the first part of course fits here. There is some rudimentary offline part with that, but I cannot tell in detail as I don't use that. Also see my list on [Personal Assistants](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_personalassistants#group_839) – I've read *utter!* is capable of that, but haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @Izzy thank you for this comment.  Your comments are sometimes as useful or more useful then actual answers. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you will need the Google Now offline voice recognition.

Go to settings >> Offline speech recognition (download latest supported language files).

You can perform some offline voice actions (play music, turn on wifi, turn on flashlight)

Here is a screenshot of Google assistant offline commands:

[image: google]

To make a call while offline:

- Tap the mic on Google assistant
- Then say Call "xx" where xx is any contact
- After this it recognises the voice and identifies the contact and immediately calls the contact

See below screenshot:

[image: call]

<sup>(click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Will this let me call people?  "Call Fred"

Comment: Yes it will work

Comment: Can one force that to always work offline, even if there is a data connection available? For privacy reasons, some folks don't like to have all they say sent to and processed on "other people's computers" (aka "the cloud").

Comment: @Izzy Good question! I am not really sure if there is an option to "force offline mode" perhaps I think blocking access to internet connection using a firewall may be an option, for privacy concerns. Probably safe if the user is out of data or doesn't wish to use internet altogether :)

Comment: That's what I read. Moreover, if offline it is reported to sometimes just giving an error pointing out that "no data connection is available". But as said, "I read". For the reasons given, I didn't try – too risky for me ;)